# XOR encryption Javascript and PHP fails with some keys

Tags: php, javascript, encryption, xor

I'm trying to crypt/decrypt a $session_key string, generated by random function, in PHP and Javascript. It works but not with all strings. With some $session_key, as in example, the result it's different. You can see the result opening the browser console.

```
<?php

function xor_this($str, $key) {
    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $tmp = $str[$i];
        for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($key); $j++) {
            $tmp = chr(ord($tmp) ^ ord($key[$j]));
        }
        $result .= $tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}

#session_key generated by substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 40)
$session_key = 'h9PYAE6KceX5g7081SnjCFBpVfux3bRtmdyDWwHq';
$password = '9b06a9342b5ac4a825088a0f0c2a2e7cc091393f';


echo xor_this($session_key, $password);

?>

<html>
    <script>

        function xor_this(str,key)
        {
            var xor = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
                tmp = str[i];
                for(var j = 0; j < key.length; ++j) {
                    tmp = String.fromCharCode(tmp.charCodeAt(0) ^ key.charCodeAt(j));
                }
                xor += tmp;
            }
            return xor;
        }

        var session_key = '<?php echo $session_key?>';
        var password = '<?php echo $password?>';
        console.log(xor_this(session_key,password));

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given `$session_key` the result is the same from PHP and JavaScript.

PHP produces: `g6_VNJ9DljW:h8?7>\aeLIMYizw<m]{bkvKXxG~`

JavaScript produces: `g6_VNJ9DljW:h8?7>\aeLIMYizw<m]{bkvKXxG~`

Note that the `<` would start a new HTML tag and the browser won't show the rest of the output on the page. You have to use "view source" to see it, or make the program to call `htmlspecialchars` before outputting the result.

This isn't much of an encryption by the way: a long password doesn't give any extra protection since all of the chars are XORed together always. For example `$password=chr(15)` gives you the same results as the current password.

Comment: Maybe I can solve with encoding in base64 the string before echo it